# FirebaseUser profile photo always error when retrieving url provided

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am curious when suddenly requesting my profile photo from firebase url,it always return error 404 when previously the link was working fine. here's the link that i'm requesting https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-SHVUqguKVzI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AAomvV1NaqGjnSOWuoMUiGOvZ1WQjyP5OA/s96-c/photo.jpg.
I inspected my FirebaseUser firebaseUser, and I found there are 2 links provided by this variable where 1 is from Google and the second from Firebase. The first from Google has the same image and it works fine but my obstacle is when used firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl() it always return the second link from firebase which is always error which I suspected the link was corrupted by some means.
How to fix this?

Comment: the same problem here :/ for some of the users images has stopped loading.